# Formation of Six Letter Strings that Conform to Specific Criterias - Combination Theory

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Problem:

> How many strings of 6 characters can you create that starts and ends with the same letter (eg: "ANDREA"), reads equally forward as well as backward (eg: Consider that you are working with the capital letters of the English alphabet).

From what I understand, for these conditions to be met, the first three and last three letters will have to be the same and the permutations of the first three letters will be equal to that of the last three.

Did I miss anything? But I am not sure how to determine the combination. Can someone help me to better understand and resolve this problem?

Comment: You have interpreted the problem correctly.  Such arrangements are called palindromes.  You just have to choose the first, second, and third letters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So then would that be permutations of 2*3!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) is a word  (such as ABAABA) that reads the same way forwards as backwards.  You wish to count palindromes of length $6$ that can be formed with the capital letters of the English alphabet.  As you observed, choosing the first three letters completely determines the palindrome.  Since repetition of letters must be permitted, we have $26$ choices for each of those letters.  Hence, there are $26^3$ such words.

Comment: How did you come about the 26?

Comment: There are $26$ letters in the English alphabet, so we have $26$ choices for each position.

Comment: Oh yea, forgot about that. Thx.